# 2002 pontiac grand prix gtp fuel consumption

Tags: fuel-system, pontiac

Just recently my sending unit has broke on my gas gauge and I filled the car with gas and I am wondering if anyone knows aproximately how many km on the odometer can I go with a full tank of gas just city driving and I plan on getting it fixed as soon as I can afford to. Also will my low fuel light still come on when I get low? I am so scared of running out of gas. Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at fuelly, the average MPG for a 2002 is 23.3.  Only one of those vehicles is called out as being in the GTP trim but it keeps up with the average.  [Here are the details](http://www.fuelly.com/car/pontiac/grand%20prix).

17.5 gallons x 23.3 mpg = 407 mile range.

Changing the fuel pump on your GTP looks easier than many vehicles as the tank doesn't need to be dropped: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLFUif-0Wgk

Comment: Most cars seem to have fuel tanks which provide about a 400 mile range. Your estimate is spot on.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to determine this is to reset the odometer at each fill up.  Assuming you fill the tank to the top, you can determine your average mpg by dividing the gallons added by the miles since last fill.  Do this a few times when you would expect to be at 1/2 tank.  Then to be safe, always fill up no later than 1/4 tank according to the known tank size.

Answer (score 0):

Your Pontiac tank is listed at 17.5 gallons. Your Pontiac fuel consumption is given as 26 mpg. Quoted Miles Per Gallon(mpg) are always optimistic. If you assume your mpg is 20mpg, then from a full tank fill-up you will have a range figure of around 350 miles.

The Low Level warning light will **come on a correctly working tank unit**, but this may not be the case on a defective unit. You would be advised against relying on it coming on as an indication of fuel left in the tank.

Fill the tank with fuel, zero the trip counter, then monitor the trip counter up to around the 300 to 325 mile mark as a measure of fuel consumption. At around 325 miles on the trip counter, add fuel to the tank and re-zero the trip counter, noting how many gallons you put in to the tank. Number of gallons in times 20mpg will give you a new range figure. By counting the fuel in you need not fill the tank fully.

Have your tank unit replaced as and when you can, in the mean time carry a clearly marked fuel can of fuel secured in the boot/trunk as back up.